# if $a ≡ b\pmod {2n}$ then prove $a^2 ≡ b^2 \pmod {4n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Let $n$ be positive number, if $a \equiv b \pmod{2n}$, prove that
>   $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod{4n}$.

By the congruence in hypothesis, we have $a-b = 2nk$ where $k$ is an integer.
Then $a = b+2nk$ and $a^2 = b^2+4n^2k^2+4knb$. From this we get $a^2-b^2 = 4kn(kn+b)$.

Now I have a question here. On the right hand side, we only know that $k$ and $4$ are integers because question says nothing about $n$ and $b$. So can we go and say that $\frac{a^2-b^2}{4n} = k(kn+b)$ is an integer?

Comment: The implicit assumption when dealing with congruences implies that $k,n,b$ are integers, so $k(kn+b)$ is an integer.

Comment: Well, $k,n$, and $b$ are integers. What does that tell you?

Comment: to emphasize:  if $n$ is not an integer than the claim need not be true.  For example, take $n=\frac 32$.  Then $2n=3$.  We have $1\equiv 4 \mod(3)$ but $1^2$ is not congruent to $4^2$ $\mod(6)$

Comment: @lulu Yes I've realized that, thank you. So all the time I see modulo congruences, should I assume they are all integers even when they are not explicitly stated?

Comment: Well...I think it is less clear than some of the other posters here have claimed.  To be sure, your stated congruence ($\mod (2n)$) definitely implies that $2n$ is an integer.  But I would not say categorically that this meant that $n$ was.  Of course, rather than allow the ambiguity one should just specify what is meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative proof. Assume that $2n|(a-b)$. Then $a$ and $b$ are either both even or both odd, so $2|(a+b)$. Since $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$, we have that $4n|(a^2-b^2)$.

Comment: You have also to prove that $2|X$ and $2n|X$ implies $2\times2n|X$.

Comment: @JohnMath but I have that $2|X$ and $2n|Y$ implies that $2\times 2n|(X\times Y)$.

Comment: In this proof, we are again assuming everything is integer, right?

Comment: @user2694307 yes, we do. Usually you only work with congruences for integers.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose
$a \equiv b \bmod 2kn
$.
($k=1$ in this case.)

Then
$a
=b+2jkn
$
for some $j$,
so
$a^2
=b^2+4bkjn+4j^2k^2n^2
=b^2+4kn(bj+j^2kn)
$
so
$a^2
\equiv b^2 \bmod 4kn
$.